# Open door as the only possible way to get into the room

Tags: plot-explanation, prison-break

I was watching Season 1 episodes of *Prison Break* again, and in the last episode where they break out of the jail, Warden along with detectives are investigating the Doctor's room. One of them report to the warden that the Door was not forcefully opened. And they immediately came to conclusion that the door was kept open by some one. How did they not see that the inmates could have made a duplicate of the key (as Michael did initially before the lock was replaced)?

How is that they arrived to the conclusion that some one left the door open as the only possible way to get in to the room?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The man inspecting the lock concludes:

> "Door wasn't forced, lock wasn't picked, as far as I can tell they
>   basically just walked right in."

In saying that, it's not clear that *he* concludes the door was left open. It just implies that the prisoners either had access to a key or that the door was not locked.

The infirmary staff member who is in the room at the time exclaims (defensively):

> "I don't see how that's possible, these doors are locked down every
>   night when we leave - it's priority number 1. Only thing I can think
>   is... someone left it open for them."

It certainly seems he is implying that somebody left it open on purpose, but it's possible he meant that somebody forgot to lock it or let them inside. I think in the moment he is just trying to avoid any blame being pointed towards him and those words come out (a similar thing happens with Katie when warden threatens her; she immediately mentions Sara's relationship with Michael to protect herself by taking the focus off of her).

You should also take into account that the lock on that door was changed the day before, so maybe he didn't think it was possible for somebody to duplicate a key in that time.

I find it even stranger they didn't consider the use of the guard's keys (the one who was guarding Lincoln). It's impossible to know for sure, but you would think he had keys to access all areas (considering he was in the infirmary area alone anyway) and they knocked him out...

Comment: I think in an earlier episode it was mentioned that the **only** people who had the keys to that place were the medical staff. That might contradict an earlier episode where the inmates riot and try to get into that room. I remember them maybe taking keys from the guard that was there. I could be wrong on that though.